# implementation of velocity in unity 3D through c#

Tags: c#-4.0, unity-game-engine

I am currently working on a tennis game in 3D with unity. When the user hits the ball, say at x=0,y=5,z=0 with velocity at certain position, say z=10, what's the ball x and y coordinate after reaching z=10?

Comment: What's the balls's velocity vector before the hit?

Answer (score 0):

To obtain the ball's velocity, you have to use the ball's RigidBody.

If your script is attached as a component of your ball, you would access it through `rigidbody.velocity.magnitude`.

Answer (score 0):

Although Heilo's approach would work *perfectly*, i stress the idea of getting a direct velocity measure, e.g. Distance/Time, time being the frame during an Update in the Update() method.

This is actually very simple to do...

Just get the distance it's traveled between two update functions like so:

```
var previousPosition : Vector3;
function Update() {
    //Get the difference/distance between the previous position and the current position
    var velocity = Vector3.Distance(previousPosition, transform.position);
}
```

Because im doing this over a single frame, there is no need to compute extra math to get the velocity. However, if you wish to do it over second, you'll need to get the FPS for the game and do some math with that.. ***So i suggest that unless you want to use this direct route, use what Heilo suggests.***